# Is there a way to implement push to deploy efficiently ...?

Tags: git, bash

All the methods I've seen on line use the checkout command on a post-receive hook.

From what I understand this checks out all the files.  So if I only change one file it will still update all of them.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure git actually checks out files that already exist on the disk and already match the target?

Comment: @EtanReisner is correct: git uses the index to avoid doing unnecessary work.  In other words, it is already reasonably efficient (assuming the "it" in question is `git checkout -f`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably use to seeing is something like this:

```
git --work-tree=/home/user/public_html --git-dir=/home/user/root.git checkout -f
```

but what you can do to be more efficient is create a git directory in your deployment directory and only pull in the needed files as such:

```
cd /home/user/public_html
git pull /home/user/root.git master
```

This is a bit more efficient and sophisticated.

Comment: I question whether this is, in fact, "more efficient". I doubt git doesn't do the same content checks with `checkout` to avoid extra work that it does with `pull` (especially since pull is just `fetch` + `checkout` anyway). Not to mention that this answer requires you to have a `.git` directory in your web root which is **decidedly** undesirable and why the standard method **avoids** that.